# Bootstrap Paginator Adding multiple active class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, paginator

I am using Bootstrap Paginator and using the function below to hide first and last page button. On doing so it is adding active classes to first page button and first item and similarly to last item and last page button.

[image]

```
shouldShowPage: function (type, page, current) {
                    switch (type) {
                        case "first":
                        case "last":
                            return false;
                        default:
                            return true;
                    }
                }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: by first and last you mean < and > ?

Comment: no, first is << and last is  >>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the below code...

```
shouldShowPage: function (type, page, current) {
                    switch (type) {
                        case "first":
                        case "last":
                            $(opts.pagerSelector).find("li:first").removeClass("active");
                            $(opts.pagerSelector).find("li:last").removeClass("active");
                            return false;
                        default:
                            return true;
                    }
                },
```